# Angular 4 ng2-file-input image size validation

Tags: javascript, angular

How to validate image size? (ex: less than 2MB)
I'm using ng2-file-input for image uploading in my angular4 project.

`

```
public onAction(event: any) {
this.resImagesSize = event.currentFiles;
for (let i = 0; i < this.resImagesSize[i].size; i++) {
if (this.resImagesSize[i].size > 2000000) {
this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Error', 'Please upload less than 2MB image');
this.resImagesSize.splice(i, 1);
} else {
this.resImages = this.resImagesSize;
}
}
}
```

`

**Edit: here is my  toasterService code**
`

```
toasterconfig: ToasterConfig =
    new ToasterConfig({
      tapToDismiss: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      preventDuplicates: false,
      positionClass: 'toast-top-center'
    });
```

`

problem is when i upload more than 2 images(bigger than 2MB) it display 2 messages. How to display only one validation message ?

Comment: Can you provide the code from toasterService, my advice is to add logic to your service that only one error message is shown at a time

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst    here is my code                        

 ` toasterconfig: ToasterConfig =
    new ToasterConfig({
      tapToDismiss: true,
      timeout: 5000,
      preventDuplicates: false,
      positionClass: 'toast-top-center'
    });`

Comment: Please add it to the question

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst done

Comment: preventDuplicates: false, set this on true, and it will work as expected

Comment: @JasperSeinhorst i did.. but still it same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, that will call the service only one time, if there is one of more invalid files:

```
   public onAction(event: any) {
   this.resImagesSize = event.currentFiles;
   let sizeValid = true;
   for (let i = 0; i < this.resImagesSize[i].size; i++) {
   if (this.resImagesSize[i].size > 2000000) {
      sizeValid = false;
      this.resImagesSize.splice(i, 1);
   } else {
      this.resImages = this.resImagesSize;
  }}
   if(!sizeValid ){
      this.toasterService.pop('error', 'Error', 'Please upload less than 2MB 
      image');
    }
 }
```

Comment: And what if toy upload a too big file on the seconds try? The error isn't visible.

Comment: i think it works good for multiple file select, if there will be one or more invalid files the service is called but only once, can you explain more your case please

Comment: did you get an error? i forget ; after sizeValid = false it should be sizeValid = false;